# Cannot send Email in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I'm using codeigniter email library to send mail. The following is my **email.php library** file configuration

```
public $useragent   = 'CodeIgniter';

public $mailpath    = '/usr/sbin/sendmail'; // Sendmail path

public $protocol    = 'smtp';       // mail/sendmail/smtp

public $smtp_host   = 'smtp.mailhostbox.com';

public $smtp_user   = 'myemailid';

public $smtp_pass   = 'mypassword';

public $smtp_port   = 25;

public $smtp_timeout    = 5;

public $smtp_keepalive  = FALSE;

public $smtp_crypto = '';

public $wordwrap    = TRUE;

public $wrapchars   = 76;

public $mailtype    = 'html';

public $charset     = 'iso-8859-1';
```

and here is my send email function in controller:

```
$message = '<div>test</div>';
$this->email->message($message);
$this->email->to(ADMIN_EMAIL);
$this->email->from($email, $userName); // if $email = 'myemailid', then its working

$this->email->subject('SenderID Request');
if($path != '')
     $this->email->attach(USER_PROFILE_PATH.$path);
if($this->email->send()){
    $result = $this->User_model->senderIDStatus($senderIDID, 3);
    if($result == 1) {

         $this->session->set_flashdata('Status','success');
         $this->session->set_flashdata('Message','SenderID submitted for approval, we will notify you soon');            
    }
    else {
       $this->session->set_flashdata('Status','failure');
       $this->session->set_flashdata('Message', 'An error occured, please try again');            
    }  
}
else {
    print_r($this->email->print_debugger());
}
```

I can send email if, **$this->email->from()** is **myemailid**, which is set in email library. If I tried to send email from another email id it shows an error like 
`The following SMTP error was encountered: 553 5.7.1 : Sender address rejected: not owned by user myemailid`

Comment: Here I dont think you need Sendmail. Try to remove it. Also just like @jignedsh said belllow you are trying to send mail from a username which differs from the SMTP username.

Answer (score 0):

The mail server is rejecting your email because you're trying to send from a username which differs from the username you're logging in as, e.g. you've set the From: to be `no-reply@mydomain.com`, which is obviously not the same as `myemailid`

Comment: but in my projet, i need to allow users to send and receive emails between them. What should I do?